# How to unmount a component on route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a component at a given route, say `app.com/cars/1`

I have a sidebar with links to different cars, eg `/cars/2`, `/cars/3` etc.

The issue I'm having is when you change links, say go from `cars/1` to `cars/2`, the component doesn't unmount, and I get `componentWillReceiveProps` fired. If I go to another page with a different component, say `/trucks`, the component is unmounted and all is well.

How can I unmount my component when the route changes? I have all kinds of state and flux stuff that I want cleared for this next car. Or if not unmount, is there a typical way people handle this kind of issue? I can't imagine this isn't very common.

(note I'm using react-router)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the normal way to handle this is just to unregister and reregister your listeners, reset your state, and so on in `componentWillReceiveProps`. It's normal to create abstractions around this behavior:

```
componentWillMount: function() {
  this.setupStuff(this.props);
}

componentWillUnmount: function() {
  this.tearDownStuff();
}

componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
  this.tearDownStuff();
  this.setupStuff(nextProps);
}

setupStuff: function(props) {
  this.setState(this.getDataFromStore(props.store));
  props.store.listen(this.handler); // or whatever
}

tearDownStuff: function(props) {
  props.store.unlisten(this.handler); // or whatever
}
```

However, if you really wanted to remount your components, there are a couple options you can use.

If you don't want *any* of your components to remain mounted across route changes, you can utilize [the `createElement` option](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#createelementcomponent-props) of the router to add a unique key to the components:

```
function createElement(Component, props) {
  var key = ...; // some key that changes across route changes
  return <Component key={key} {...props} />;
}

// ...

<Router createElement={createElement}>
  ...
```

However, I don't recommend this. Not only does it make your app slower because *every* route component is remounting each time, but it also completely disables things like animations between subsequent renders of the same route handler with different props.

If you only want a *certain* route to always rerender, you can give it a key in the parent via `React.cloneElement`:

```
render: function() {
  var key = ...; // some key that changes across route changes
  return React.cloneElement(
    React.Children.only(this.props.children),
    {key: key}
  );
}
```

Comment: Still relevant now, However, its not easy to reset state if your state is coming from a hook you don't control.

Comment: @cdosborn Yeah. I think I would probably wrap the hook usage in a sub-component, and render it with a changing `key` prop as necessary based on some other data from a wrapping component to enable a forced remount. See https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key

Answer (score 3):

I ended up just doing:

```
const createElement = (Component, props) =>
  <Component key={props.params.id} {...props}/>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory} createElement={createElement}>
    <Route path="courses/:id" component={Page_courses_id}/>
  </Router>
);
```

and ignoring potential performance issues (if they ever occur), in my mind maintenance cost (of resetting state of all components under :dynamic-segment, of refetching data in componentWillReceiveProps, etc.) is not worth it.

Comment: I have somewhat similar case...a sidebar which can open and close on left and on right i have dhtmlx-scheduler component.On page reload everything works fine, but when i go to Route3 and come back to Route2 on which sidebar and dhtmlx-cheduler are present, then on opening the sidebar, the scheduler component should adjust its width according to the width left when sidebar is expanded, but some portion of scheduler is cut off. On page hard refresh, although it works fine, and adjust its width perfectly when sidebar is expanded. Should i unmount scheduler component everytime route changes.

Comment: Please find the github link attached
     https://github.com/sonalk215/dhtml

Any pointers will be really elpful

Comment: @sk215, I'm sure you'll have more luck submitting this as a question.

Comment: I raised a new question, thanks for the suggestion lakesare

Question link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64563819/react-with-dhtmlx-scheduler

Answer (score 1):

I chose the Michelle Tilley option with change key, but I did not set the key for the entire component in the router, but only for the one where I needed to update with restarting the hooks.

This works great.

```js
const UniqComponent = () => {
  const uniqId = 123; // may be carId
  return <div key={uniqId} />
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="cars/:id" component={UniqComponent}/>
  </Router>
);
```